On a probabilistic integer factorization algorithm given bounds for one prime factor
We got a probabilistic integer factorization algorithm and experimental evidence with large
integers given bounds for one factor.
Let $D \ge 2$ be real number and let $p,q$ be primes and $N=pq$.
Assume $\log{q} \sim D\log{p}$.
Let $B_1,B_2$ be real numbers such that $B_1 < q < B_2$
and $B_2 - B_1 < C q^\frac{D-1}{D}$ for an absolute constant $C$.
Given $N,D,B_1,B_2$ our algorithm experimentally finds the factor
$q$ efficiently with complexity $O(\log N)$.
The algorithm may fail, but according to our tests it fails rarely.

Q1 Is this result known?


Q2 Given $N,D$ what is the best complexity to find $B_1,B_2$,
possibly assuming some properties of $q$?


Since there is only one partial answer, me and Stefcho Guninski
released a preprint and sagemath source code that may run in a browser
For real $x$ and natural $N$, define $J(x,N)=\sin{\frac{\pi N}{x}}$.
The real zeros of $J$ are $\frac{N}{a}$ for integer $a$.
The integer zeros of $J$ are the divisors of $N$.
For small $x$, the real zeros are very dense, but in some
cases we can find interval which contains only one zero, which
is integer.
To illustrate, take $N=5*37$ and examine the plot $x \in (1,N)$:

To illustrate a good interval,
take $N=5*37$ and examine the plot $x \in (37-\sqrt{37},37+\sqrt{37})$
and observe that it contains only one real zero, which is the integer
factor $37$.

For real constant $D \ge 2$
and $N=pq$ with $\log{q} \approx D \log{p}$
and given bounds $B_1 < q < B_2$ and $ 0 < q-B_1,B_2-q < q^{\frac{D-1}{D}}$ we find the factor $q$ in time polynomial in $\log{N}$ using real root finding of the function
$J(x,N)=\sin{\frac{\pi N}{x}}$
To find the unique zero, we use mpmath's function
|mpmath.findroot(J,B_1,B_2)|
Experimentally it finds the zero efficiently using real root
To our surprise, for $p \sim 2^{400},D=4$, generating the primes
$p,q$ in $5.6$ seconds and the root finding took only $27$ms.

Please expand on the word, "efficiently".

May I send you a challenge factorisation?

Doesn't the Elliptic Curve Method scale with the size of the smaller factor? It would still be super-polynomial but might make a good practical point of comparison.

@Aurel Sure, send me a few challenges, my email is on my profile page.

@BillBradley I don't see the relation with elliptic curves and my bound is different than the Hasse bound.

@Aurel If you send me challenge, please include D=3 and B_2-B_1 < C q^(1/3)

@BillBradley In the elliptic curve case you must know the order of the curve, not a range for it.

@joro q^(1/3) or q^(2/3) ? For D=3 the exponent you wrote in the question is (D-1)/D = 2/3. Can I take C=1?

By the way, did you really mean O(log N), i.e. linear complexity, or polynomial complexity?

@Aurel I mean polynomial in log(N), but it is vow degree polynomial according to my tests. Not entirely sure.

If $D\le 3$, it is known how to do this in polynomial time by Coppersmith's algorithm [Cop96]: note that $q \approx N^{\frac{D}{D+1}}$ and therefore $B_2-B_1 \approx q^{\frac{D-1}{D}} \approx N^{\frac{D-1}{D+1}}$, so you known $\approx \frac{1}{D+1}\log_2 N$ bits of $q$.
[Cop96] D. Coppersmith, Finding a small root of a bivariate integer equation; factoring with high bits known, EUROCRYPT 96. ZbMath

Thanks. I don't understand your answer. Set D=3, L=q^(2/3). If you multiply integer by irrational, you are losing bits. How do you find the bits given B_1=q - sqrt(2)*L, B_2=q+sqrt(3)*L? What if you are given other similar pairs of B_1,B_2?In addition you can get L smaller, say L=q^(1/3), and you don't have equality but inequality.

@joro Having an interval containing an integer is equivalent to knowing its highest bits. The interval being non-rational does not matter, you can round it to a narrower interval with integer endpoints.

Thanks. Sorry but I still fail to understand how many highest bits a range of M integers defines. If you accept challenges and I give you different pairs of B_1,B_2 will you still get the same highest bits?

@joro Think about what the set of integers with $a$ fixed bits followed by $b$ unspecified bits is. That's the integer interval $[A2^b,A2^b+2^b-1]$, were $A$ is a number with $a$ bits. So knowing the highest $a$ bits of an $a+b$ bits number is equivalent to locating it in an interval of this form. In any case, you should read Coppersmith's article: the number of bits is simply the motto, but you will see that the proofs are in terms of knowing an interval containing the the factor to be found.

Thanks. I edited adding a preprint, sagemath code and experimental data. Hope you improve the algorithm.

Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484302/given-n-pq-with-what-complexity-we-can-find-integer-a-q-sqrtq-a-q-s
