Given $N=pq$, with what complexity we can find integer $a : q-\sqrt{q} < a <q+\sqrt{q}$?
Related to open problem and this question.
Let $N=p q$ be integer with unknown factorization. We are looking for an answer which can be used in factorization algorithm, so factoring $N$ is not allowed.

Q1 Given $N=pq$, with what complexity we can find integer $a : q-\sqrt{q} < a <q+\sqrt{q}$?

Assume that an oracle answers if given integer satisfies the inequality.
Something subexponential in $\log{q}$ will be of great interest.
Trivial upper bound of $O(\sqrt{q})$. Choose upper bound $B$ for $q$.
Try $\sqrt{B}$ random integers in the range $(1,B)$.
Let $D$ be real constant $ 0 < B <1$.

Q2 Given $N,B$, with what complexity we can find integer
$a : q-q^B < a <q+q^B$?

By the above construction we get $O(q^{1-B})$.
Q1 Is related to the order of the elliptic curve over $GF(q)$.
Using smooth integers, in subexponential time we get multiple
of $a$, but recovering $a$ depends on many small factors.

How do you distinguish $p$ and $q$...?

@KevinCasto It doesn't matter which of the primes satisfy the inequality

So basically you're taking the union of the intervals, $(p-\sqrt p, p+\sqrt p) \cup (q-\sqrt q, q + \sqrt q)$? So if $N=299$, then $a$ can either be in $10,\dots,16$ or $19,\dots,27$?

@KevinCasto Yes, that is right and I would be glad to accept it as an answer. Thanks for you interest in the question.
